# Nginx when client certificate verification is canceled

Tags: nginx, client-certificates

i'm setting up a nginx reverse-proxy, which require a client certificate verification:

```
ssl_verify_client on;
ssl_client_certificate /etc/nginx/<certificate>.crt;
ssl_crl /etc/nginx/<crl>.crl;
ssl_verify_depth 2;
```

When the user open the url in his browser and click on the Cancel-Button in the certificate selection pop-up, the nginx send a http 400 response with a error-page to the user.
Then, when the user tries to reload the url, the certificate selection pop-up isn't shown any more and the user has to close his browser (even all tabs). After he reopens the browser and open the url, die certificate selection pop-up will be displayed again.

Can i configure the nginx, that the certificate verification is required every time the url is requested, even after an abort?